# Android Checkbox text merge into checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I am using checkbox in my app, in some devices like Redmi 1S,micromax Yureka, sony xperia L etc it works fine but for micromax Canvas 4 and other small screen size mobiles of samsung the checkbox text enters or merge into the checkbox. Is their any solution...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <requestFocus />

    <requestFocus />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.46"
        android:button="@drawable/selecter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:textSize="@dimen/question_size"

        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.46"
        android:textSize="@dimen/question_size"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:button="@drawable/selecter"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.46"
        android:textSize="@dimen/question_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:button="@drawable/selecter"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.46"
        android:textSize="@dimen/question_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:button="@drawable/selecter"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Micromax Canvas 4] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your checkbox add `android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_checkbox"`
Based on where you need the right dimensions you need to set the value in the correct values file. For example

**In values**

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="space_checkbox">20dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

**In values-v17 (4.2)**

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="space_checkbox">10dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Comment: weleome.. I am glad it did